# quantile regression vs mannU (median difference)

Tags: time-series, median, quantile-regression

I want to compare the medians of an interrupted time series, for example, years 2019-2020 with 2021-2022. The data is not normally distributed and the distribution of the data is not similar.

Would quantile regression be appropriate here? Should I expect to see similarities between mood median test and quantile regression?

I am looking at the rate of abx prescribed (standardized by patient days) in a group of hospitals. The research question is, was the rate of abx prescribed different between the two time periods (before vs after the interruption). I am doing a full ITS - this is just a preliminary/descriptive part.
@user2974951

Thanks-

Comment: What is your research question? What exactly do you want to compare?

Comment: If you've got time trends, in what way does it make sense to talk about comparing medians of the marginal distribution rather than comparing conditional distributions? (at least that's what you seem to be implying you're looking at e.g. in phrasing like 'the distribution of the data')

Comment: I think it is poor wording on my part. It is conditional, relative to the interruption.